# strange adb behaviour if script is piped into bash

Tags: linux, bash, adb

I stumpled upon a strange behaviour that I can not explain. I tried to narrow down the problem. I have the following test testscript.sh script:

```
echo before
adb shell ls
echo after
```

If I run the script with `bash -x testscript.sh`, everything works as expected and I get the following output:

```
+ echo before
before
+ adb shell ls
acct
bin
bugreports
...
sdcard
storage
sys
system
ueventd.rc
vendor
+ echo before
before
```

But if I run the script as piped script with `cat testscript.sh | bash -sx`, I get the following output:

```
+ echo before
before
+ adb shell ls
acct
bin
bugreports
...
sdcard
storage
sys
system
ueventd.rc
vendor
```

The last `echo after` is not executed, and I can not figure out why. The script is running on an Ubuntu server 18.04. The adb is the one from the official Ubuntu package.

```
$ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Please could someone enlight me, what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a script with `bash scriptname`, standard input of all the commands it runs is still connected to the terminal. So `adb` will read its standard input from the terminal.

When you redirect the input of `bash`, this redirection is inherited by `adb`. Unless you use the `-n` option to `adb shell`, it will read additional input from standard input and send it to the remote system as possible input for the command you run (it doesn't know that `ls` doesn't read standard input).

Change it to

```
adb shell -n ls
```